# How do I combine many commands in one command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know how I can combine many commands in one command block, like setblock, fill, give and so on.

Comment: I have linked a question that has been asked about this already, however this question does have a better answer, so it might me more beneficial to link it the other way.

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible in Vanilla. You can only have one command per command block. However, you can trigger a lot of command blocks with just one, using scoreboards, setblock or summoning commandblocks holding redstone holding a command block and etc. by using a automatic generator. The 2 first solutions are listed below, if you want the third one, search "one command block filter".

---

Create a scoreboard with `/scoreboard objectives create <objectivename> dummy`, on the command block you want to execute various commands do `/scoreboard players set @r <objectivename> 1` and then in some command blocks on really fast clocks (`/setblock ~-1 ~ ~ redstone_block` and `/setblock ~1 ~ ~ air`) do tests like `execute @a[score_<objectivename>_min=1] ~ ~ ~ <command>` on various blocks and in the last one do `scoreboard players set @a <objectivename> 0`.

---

Do `/setblock <location> redstone_block` on the commandblock to execute various actions and then on that location hook up a wire with the commands, being on the end a `/setblock <location> air`.